# Weka in R not working - unable to load weka packages via WPM

Tags: java, r, weka, wpm

I am trying to use the RWeka package in R (Studio). After having installed JAVA to match R (64 bit) I created a WEKA_HOME directory where I have put the folder 'wekafiles' earlier stored elsewhere.
So, to summarize, I get an error when trying to install a weka package, e.g.:

> WPM("install-package", "optics_dbSCan")
>   Error in .jcall(wpm, "Z", "installPackageFromRepository", args[1L], version,  : 
>     java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\wekafiles\repCache\optics_dbSCan\Latest.props (The system cannot find the path specified)

I've read a lot of threads related to it, but was not able to find a solution which would Weka make work.I really tried several things, but without ever even getting a Weka package installed.

Additional infos: "HOME_" directories:

> Sys.getenv('WEKA_HOME')
>   [1] "C:\dev\wekafiles"
>   Sys.getenv('JAVA_HOME')
>   [1] "c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\"
>   Sys.getenv('R_HOME')
>   [1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0"

Installed packages: RWeka, RWekajars, rJava
Working with RStudio Version 1.0.143
Windows 10, R and Java on 64bit

Any hint is welcome, thanks!

Comment: have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably seen the instructions in class 3 here.

https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/mooc/advanceddataminingwithweka/

I particularly liked slide 30:
"What can possibly go wrong?
Many things ..., too many to cover here!"

When I set this up it didn't work -- it turned out I was one directory level off (I don't remember if it was one directory level too high or too low.)

This hint may be of help, but otherwise all I can offer is sympathy. Good luck.

I note the course this material is part of is being offered on FutureLearn in November (free). That might be an opportunity to ask Witten himself.

Comment: Can you please advise on how to calculate ROC AUC through rWeka?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Running:

```
WPM("refresh-cache")
```

solved it.